# can't get parameter from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, servlets, xmlhttprequest

I can see parameters from js, but I can't use getParameter to get them. what's the problem?

js code

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
req.open("POST", "../PersonTest", true);
req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            alert(req.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("HTTP error " + req.status + ": " + req.statusText);
        }
    }
}
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.send("email=" + email + "&password=" + password);
```

servlet code

```
    response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
    try {  
        //print request content
        ServletInputStream is = request.getInputStream();   
        ... 
        System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray(), "utf-8"));

        //get parameter
        String email = request.getParameter("email");  
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println(email + "  " + password);

    }
```

servlet output:
email=123&password=123
null  null

Comment: You perform a `POST` request, so the servlet assumes the parameters are in the request body and not in the query string...

Comment: Do you mean that getParameter() is not for request body?
How can I get key-value pairs from request body?

Comment: Just read the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)

Comment: @user2138279, You can definitely use request.getParameter(). What is that servlet output ? How did you get it if you are not able to get the request parameters ?

Comment: Problem solved. Thx guys. I found that I needed to set character encoding first. just add `code`(request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");)